# MySQL find all row exactly one week earlier from today

Tags: mysql, date

I tried to find a MySQL snippet on Stackoverflow before posting but it result to nothing.

I have a code where I need to display all "items" that have been posted 8 days from now only. So for example, we are the 10-29-2015. The MySQL would return me items with a created date of 10-21-2015. Items from 10-22-2015 should not be counted.

So far, my MySQL query logic looks like :

> SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE *date older then 7 days and lower then 9 days*

In my MySQL structure, the field **start_date** has a type of **date**.

I think the best way to do it would be to do something like this :

```
WHERE TODAY = start_date + 7 DAYS
```

EDIT1 : With the given comment, my query should be :

```
SELECT * FROM `my_table` WHERE `start_date` = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 8 DAY;
```

Comment: `SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL 8 DAY;`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
WHERE `start_date` BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 9 DAY) AND (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Comment: The OP appears only interested in things which are exactly 8 days old.

Comment: And start_date is a DATE data type, so this is slightly overkill